# Looping that will not be duplicated

Tags: php, sql, loops

- 1000
- 2000
- 3000
- 3000
- 4000
- 4000
- 4000
  I want to echo them without duplicating in php. i think it's a looping can you help me

Comment: **this should help you :**

    echo "<ul>";
    $tab= array(1000,2000,3000,3000,4000);
    foreach($tab as $val){
    echo "<li>$val</li>";
    }
    echo "</ul>";

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
$arr = array(1000,2000,3000,3000,4000,4000,4000);
print_r(array_unique($arr));
```

Check [this for more](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php)

Comment: i can see duplication. :)